# Windows Server 2016 (Azure) Display Language Change Causes Activation Warning

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

Having recently deployed a number of Windows Server 2016 Data Centre VMs in Azure we noticed that the default locale/keyboard/display languages were set to English US.

We subsequently went about changing all of these to English UK which appeared to be ok, however, we now notice that on changing the Display Language for all users we can no longer customise any settings (In the control panel we get an error stating that we need to activate the machine before we can personalise it)

Slmgr reports activation is fine so I'm a bit stuck.  I've tried re-activating which reports all is fine.  Language pack downloaded ok with no errors.  Anyone ever come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the display language to English US and then recheck to see if the activation succeeds.

Generally, Azure VM activation issues occur if the Windows VM is not configured by using the appropriate KMS client setup key, or the Windows VM has a connectivity problem to the Azure KMS service (kms.core.windows.net, port 1668).

Step 1: Configure the appropriate KMS client setup key (for Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2012 R2)
If your Azure VM is not activating, and if it was created from a custom image of Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2012 R2, you must configure the appropriate KMS client setup key for the VM.

Step 2 Verify the connectivity between the VM and Azure KMS service

1. Download and extract the Psping tool to a local folder in the VM that does not activate.
2. Go to Start, search on Windows PowerShell, right-click Windows PowerShell, and then select Run as administrator.
3. Make sure that the VM is configured to use the correct Azure KMS server. To do this, run the following command:
4. iex “$env:windir\system32\cscript.exe $env:windir\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms
5. kms.core.windows.net:1688
   The command should return: Key Management Service machine name set to kms.core.windows.net:1688 successfully.
6. Verify by using Psping that you have connectivity to the KMS server. Switch to the folder where you extracted the Pstools.zip download, and then run the following command: 
              \psping.exe kms.core.windows.net:1688
7. Also, verify that the guest firewall has not been configured in a manner that would block activation attempts.
8. After you verify successful connectivity to kms.core.windows.net, run the following command at that elevated Windows PowerShell prompt. This command tries activation multiple times.
9. 1..12 | % { iex “$env:windir\system32\cscript.exe $env:windir\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato” ; start-sleep 5 }

Refer https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4011286/no-key-management-service-kms-could-be-contacted-when-you-try-to-activ for more details.